# Office 365 apps

Tags: office-365

I am new to Office 365. Can any one tell me whether custom webparts (sandboxed) cabe be built as an app to sharepoint online? is yes the how a webpart can be published as an app ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you have a look at this! it outlines everything that you would need to know! it should also be a very good starting point! the sandbox solutions can be found near the bottom what goes into detail. Yes it a big read but it answers all your questions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317460.aspx

hope it helps :)

**Edit**

Office 365 for developers download for VS2012 (download and install)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627.aspx

Blog - someone who istalled the above to develp on VS

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9745/installed-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio.aspx

How to: Install the Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime Redistributable

> 1. Install the .NET Framework 4.  • To download the .NET Framework 4, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178957.
>
> • To download the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178958.
>
> 1. Run vstor40_x86.exe or vstor40_x64.exe to install the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime. Choose the setup file that matches your
>      computer architecture (x86 or x64).
>
> These setup files are available on the Visual Studio installation
>   media, and they are also available for download at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=140384. The prerequisites for
>   the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime are the same as the
>   prerequisites for the .NET Framework.
>
> 1. Install the language pack for the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime if you use non-English settings for Windows, and you
>      want to see runtime messages in the same language that you use for
>      Windows. If any end users run your solutions with non-English settings
>      for Windows, they must have the correct language pack to see runtime
>      messages in the same language as Windows. The language pack is
>      available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=140386.
>
> If you need ClickOnce non-English language support during the
>   deployment and installation of your solution, install the .NET
>   Framework Language Packs. The language packs are available from the
>   Microsoft Download Center.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178739.aspx

Office Development in Visual Studio

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx

hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks:) and one more thing I wanted to ask is I have installed VS 2012 ultimate and I have office 365 preview. I just cant see the office developer tools for visual studio 2010..i cant even see ay templates for sharepoint/office either

Comment: check out the edited answer for installing and configuring vs, the second link is documentation on hoto guides with office 365

Answer (score 1):

Since your looking for developing a webpart for Office 365, you can follow this tutorial, it shows you everything step by step

[office 365 webpart tutorial](http://sp365.co.uk/2011/07/build-a-simple-web-part-for-office-365-that-gets-data-from-a-list/)

Answer (score 0):

I would not name web part as application and I never bother about sanboxing since it is impossible to have non-sandboxed apps in Office 365.

The easiest way for a newbie to develop a web part is to publish any Infopath form which then appear in list of available Infopath web parts. The latter you can see/use by navigating to or create in web browser to any web part ASPX page in Sharepoint online (Office 365) site > click **Add a web part** link >  Forms (under Categories) > Infopath Form Web Part > Add > **Click here to open the tool pane** link > in tool pane under **List or Library:** list box you will see the list of published Infopath forms

[image]

The easiest way to create and publish an Infopath form is to navigate in browser to any list in Sharepoint online site > click **Customize Form** on ribbon > in Opened Infopath Designer 2010 click **Quick Publish** button (on ribbon **File** > **Info**) ... after or without its editing

That's it, you have developed, published and used ("sandboxed") web part.