# Office developer tools for Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, office-365

I have installed

- Windows 7 32 bit OS
- Visual studio 2012 ultimate

I also have office365 preview(sharepoint online) I need to develop an app for office365. But I have downloaded the tools from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/apps/fp123627). which will open Web Platform Installer(WPI) but I cant find any tool related to office development. Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iv just answered someone else with the same question, please refer to these guides. To configure vs2012 look at the edit part (first link) the second link shows everything you need to know about 365 development :)

[Office 365 apps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43936/office-365-apps/43938#comment40638_43938)

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

would you like to go through this guide as am pretty sure it will help you with initial development of office365 provided by Microsoft

[office365 development training kit by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365trainingcourse.aspx)